# Encoding a column of a data set in R using factor

Tags: r

I just started learning data science and ML from udemy and there in one tutorial where the instructor use R to encode the categorical data in a data set by using factor function.I have the following data set :-[Original Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8oEz.jpg)

I've already cross-checked my code with instructor's code like 100 times but still can't figure out what is wrong with my code, so please help me?

I write the following code :-

```
    dataset$Country = factor(dataset$Country,
                     levels = c('France','Spain','Germany'),
                     labels = c(1,2,3))
```

When I run the above code then the column that I encoded showing 'NA' for each value of column as shown in this image :-[Dataset after executing above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgawM.jpg)

Comment: Please check the values of 'Country' column for any leading/lagging spaces.  Try `factor(trimws(dataset$Country),  ...` e.g. `v1 <- c(" France", "Spain ", "Germany "); factor(v1, levels = c('France','Spain','Germany'), labels = 1:3)` and then with `factor(trimws(v1), levels = c('France','Spain','Germany'), labels = 1:3)`

Comment: You almost certainly don't want `labels = c(1, 2, 3)`, or you'll end up with factors of numbers which are internally stored as numbers. They'll line up in this case, but generally using numbers for factor labels just makes everything confusing.

Comment: Please be print an post original dataset

Comment: @akrun Thanks brother your method helped me and now everything run perfectly.